# Using Unicode Values in C#

Tags: c#, unicode, unicode-escapes

I am getting this weird occurrence when using unicodes in my application. I have a list of random unicodes which I then randomly assign to an object.

```
var icons = new List<string> { "\uf022", "\uf039", "\uf02b", "\uf1b2", "\uf07b" };
```

When I debug the object the `Object.Icon` property shows `"."` which is the correct value for unicode. When I display the unicodes on a XAML page the correct icons are displayed.

[image: Unicode from application list]

So when I got this working I wanted to move the unicode values into the database instead of making it random. But now when I debug the object the `Object.Icon` property shows "`\\unicodevalue"` i.e "\uf022".

[image]

When displaying this value on the XAML page, its being displayed as the text value \uf022 instead of an icon.

What is the difference between the strings in the icons list and having the string value in the database?

Comment: You'll need to debug the code that puts these values in the database and retrieves them, as that's where things are going wrong. Just observing the end result only tells you that there's a problem, not what it is.

Comment: The values in the database are the exact same values that are in the random icons list though. This code is on retrieval.

Comment: Then you've narrowed it down to the code that retrieves things, I'd say. To be clear: the string consisting of the single character `U+F022` is not the same string as the string `\uf022`. Your database can (probably) store either, but make sure you're not confounded by tools that don't display things accurately. If using SQL Server, for example, use `DATALENGTH` to get the string size in bytes, and things like `CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), [column])` to see the actual contents in code points. (Note also that `U+F022` is an unassigned private use character and can be displayed as whatever.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unicode sequences in the database have their backslash escaped, so `"\\uf042"` is really 6 characters altogether: the backslash, "u", "f", "0", "4" and "2".

The unicode sequences in your code however, are really just one character as far as C# is concerned, They are literals of unicode code points.

To change from the values in your database to individual unicode code points, try the [`Char.ConvertFromUtf32`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.convertfromutf32(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Comment: I've changed the code that saved the unicode into the database to instead save the decimal value. I can then use Char.ConvertFromUtf32 to covert to the icon.